# Not able to run the Angular application in browser

Tags: .net, typescript, visual-studio-2017, npm-install, angular2-template

I have followed [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9iK2Eib85E) for installing Angular related files like TypeScript and all its JS files. So after installing when I run the application using command prompt, I got the below error

[image: IMG]

But the same was working fine in the video tutorial.

Note: The only thing which my application didn't had while installing was `node_modules` file. Rest all the thing was perfect.

I am new to Angular and started learning its installation with Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Please add the error text to your question, so we may copy any relevant bits?

Comment: OT - Why are you looking at an Angular 2 demo? If this is something you're learning, you'd be better off using Angular 9!

Comment: @phuzi yes but the installation issue will still remain the same I guess ?

Comment: If you're using latest version, then any bugs will likely have been fixed by now (assuming you're not already using latest versions of any tools - not just tsc).

Comment: No I m using it for the first time..

Comment: I would still make an effort to find a demo that's a bit more up to date though.

Comment: @phuzi: ok, can u find me one for the same with installing ??

Comment: Nope, sorry. Finding off-site resources is OT for StackOverflow.

Comment: Try the Angular.io Getting Started guide though.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to use `tsc --project src/`. It should work fine.

More details [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html).

As someone mentioned, why are you using an old guide that use Angular2? And also, Visual Studio is really useless along typescript. In my personal opinion just use VS code.

Comment: Ok will try and update u accordingly on monday, as I left for the day.. thanks in advance

Comment: where should I add it `tsc --project src/` .Please help. and how to set Up `VS code` for using angular

Comment: you don't have two add it anywhere, is just a command that should allow you to do what you wanted to do. For VS Code, simply install it and then open a folder that holds your Angular project and you're done.